# rosserial failed under Ubuntu 11.10 ROS electric

Tags: arduino, rosserial, ubuntu-oneiric, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying rosseial with Arduino based IR range finder.
Ubuntu 11.10   ROS electric

The details is as below:

[INFO] [WallTime: 1320969440.580833] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1320969440.584986] Connected on /dev/ttyUSB0 at 57600 baud
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1320969442.700559] Creation of publisher failed: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1320969442.718333] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1320969442.777416] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1320969442.837355] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1320969442.896387] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125

Anybody knows what's the problem? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11890/rosserial-failed-under-ubuntu-11.10-ros-electric/) by [bona](https://answers.ros.org/users/1158/bona/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2011-11-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on 2012-12-10**:
I've tried updating to the latest arduino 1.0.2 and the latest rosserial under electric with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like you upgraded the computer to rosserial 0.3.0, but did not update your Arduino libraries and/or re-upload the code to the Arduino. We recently added the md5 checksum to each topic negotiation so that users are alerted about changes in messages (which causes difficult to debug errors).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1